# How to access local variable outside of a function

Tags: android, cordova

Here, i am not sure why error function is not working if the C_id comming from server is incorrect. i am getting C_id from server database and passing that C_id to other server in ajax request.

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://proserve.ekspeservices.com/client.php",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {type: 'login', id: C_id},// getting C_id from server, but here if C_id is incorrect error function is not working
        ContentType: "application/json",
        error: function()
        {
            navigator.notification.alert('inCorrect Key');
        },
        success: function(res) 
        {

            var simpleJson = JSON.parse(res);

            myDB.transaction(function (txe1) 
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < simpleJson.User.length; i++) 
                {
                    var Cli_id= simpleJson.User[i].id;
                    myDB.transaction(function (txe) 
                    {
                        txe.executeSql('CREATE TABLE Client_data(Mobile integer , C_id integer, U_id integer , name text , ip integer )');

                    }); 

                    myDB.transaction(function (txe1) 
                    {

                        var data_ins = 'INSERT INTO Client_data (Mobile,C_id,U_id) VALUES (?,?,?)';
                        txe1.executeSql(data_ins, [p,C_id,U_id]
                        ,function(tx, result)
                        {
                            navigator.notification.alert('Inserted' ,  onSignup, 'Info', 'ok'); 

                        },
                        function(error)
                        {
                            navigator.notification.alert('Already Registered'); 
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }   
    });
```

Comment: If you  have any further please make a new post as that will help us understand what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of i must tell,you are trying to access the variable in your case its `client_id` whose scope is within that ftr() only.

So you need to define it globally to access it, also you need to define it as an array as you are getting multiple values at a time so you need to push in that.
Your code will be some what like this.

Also you need to call the `ab()` function after `ftr()` is finished executing as `ab()` output is dependent on `ftr()` result.So, you can go with Jquery deferred or simply call `ab()` within `ftr()` as below

```
var client_id = [];
function ftr()
{
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction)
    { 
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User_data', [], function (tx, results)
        {

        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
        {     
            var emp = results.rows.item(i);
            client_id.push({
                id: emp.C_id,                   
            });                
        }
    }, null);
    });
    ab();
}

function ab(){
  console.log(client_id);
}

function onDeviceReady()
{
    myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb.db", location: 'default'});

    ftr();        
}
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: thaknx..it worked...but i have one more question. how to ensure that data sent on server is incorrect as i am not able to print the error msg..code updated above, plz refer

Comment: If that worked accept it as answer....Also add new question with detailed description for your another problem

Answer (score 0):

Make public that variable outside of the function simple
like this

```
public yourVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try defining the variable OUTSIDE of the function, and then pass it as a parameter to the function.

This way it can be assigned a value and be used elsewhere.